# TinyMCE - image re-size handles disappear after re-size

Tags: image, resize, tinymce

After resizing an image in TinyMCE in Fire Fox, the re-size handles disappear. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? I don't have this problem anymore in the latest version of TinyMCE. What I used to do is blur the iframe and then if you click on the image again you can resize it.